# Show hide button on a tableview cell,ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

I am trying to initially hide the button on a `UITableViewCell` and want to show that button when I click on the label on the same `UITableViewCell`. I tried setting `isEnabled` and `userInteraction = YES/NO`, but no luck.
Please tell me any other method ??

Comment: Try adding a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to your label.

Comment: @user3969152: Can you please share your code for a better understanding of your problem?

Answer (score 1):

`button.hidden = YES` is the normal way to hide UIView-based elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your tableview cell's class, you can initially hide the cell's button as shown in the code below:

```
class SettingsTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblLanguage: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnArrow: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        btnArrow.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Later in the select delegate of the tableview, you can get access to the button of that particular cell and unhide the button.

Let me know if further help is required.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, this code is Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it like following way, I hope it will help you:

**1)** Assign a tag to each button in `if` statement :

```
buttonFlag.tag = indexPath.row:
```

**2)** Find the button by its tag and set **hidden** in `else` statement :

```
else if ([[self.flags objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"true"])
{
 UIButton *buttonFlag = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
 [buttonFlag setHidden:YES];
}
```